# Transfer pictures via NFC

Tags: android, storage, nfc

So I am making a project for my android class at school.

The project is about helping handicaped people communicating with a nurse if they can't speak. The solution I've come up with is an app where 24 pictures is combined with 24 sound files which the user then can use to communicate. For example, by taking a picture with a helper and then the nurse records the word on a tablet then when next time the user needs to get an apple he/she just presses the apple on the app and it says apple.

What would optimize this app would be that instead of each user of the app having a tablet, the nurse only has one. Then when entering the house of a user he/she can by scanning a NFC chip, get the pictures and sound files into the app belonging to that person.

So here's the question. Can this be done by combining a NFC chip with some sort of SD card solution or will this have to be done by the chip returning for example an URL with some sort of user parameter getting the pictures and soundfiles by using an internet connection?

So is there some storage thing you can put together with an nfc chip that could make this posible?

Comment: I do not expect much success with your question - you simply did not do any research on your own, so expect downvotes and close requests.

Comment: Thanks for constructive criticism I guess..